# MySQL, Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `iRecipes`.`searches`.`id` (php)

Tags: php, mysql

When I try inserting my data into the database, it says "Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column `iRecipes`.`searches`.`id`"

Wondering how I fix this?

```
DB::query(
    'INSERT INTO searches VALUES(\'\', :token, :typeSearch, :search, :ip)',
    array(
        ':token' => $token, 
        ':typeSearch' => $type, 
        ':search' => $recipeName, 
        ':ip' => $ip
    )
);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: i think the problem is `\'\', ` at the beggining of `VALUES(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an empty string to column `id`, which is numeric, hence the error that you are getting.

You should consider not passing this column for insert, so the `auto_increment` will automatically assign the next value. This is what auto-incremented primary keys are about.

This requires you to explicitly list the other columns you are assigning:

```
DB::query(
    'INSERT INTO searches(token, typeSearch, search, ip) 
        VALUES(:token, :typeSearch, :search, :ip)', 
    array(
        ':token' => $token, 
        ':typeSearch' => $type, 
        ':search' => $recipeName, 
        ':ip' => $ip
    )
);
```

Comment: In fact, one must always list the columns for an insert query.

Comment: @SalmanA: I would agree on that. That's a best practice. It is just not technically mandatory to do so.